# htaccess mapping old url for redirect 301

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have old site like this

```
http://www.dmbitalia.net/articolo_articlename
```

I would like to have redirect to

```
http://www.dmbitalia.com/articlename-articolo.html
```

I have a lot of link with this structure, only change `articlename` part.
I don't know how to write a regex rule in `.htaccess`, can anybody help me?

i have already this on my .htaccess

```
    #RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^_]+)_([^_/]+)/?$ http://www.dmbitalia.com/$1-$2.html
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^articoli_([^/]+)$ prodotti.php?seo_url=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^dmb_strumenti_musicali_([^/]+)$ prodotti.php?seo_url=$1&sottocategoria1=1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^dmbitalia_strumenti_musicali_([^/]+)$ prodotti.php?seo_url=$1&sottocategoria2=1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^strumenti_musicali_([^/]+)$ macro_categorie2.php?seo_url=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^marca_([^/]+)$ prodotti.php?seo_url=$1&marca=1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^articolo_([^/]+)$ prodotti_descrizione.php?seo_url=$1 [QSA]
#RewriteRule ^pippo contatti.php [QSA]

# 5G BLACKLIST/FIREWALL (2013)
# @ http://perishablepress.com/5g-blacklist-2013/

# 5G:[QUERY STRINGS]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\"|%22).*(<|>|%3) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (javascript:).*(\;) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C).*script.*(>|%3) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\\|\.\./|`|=\'$|=%27$) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\;|\'|\"|%22).*(union|select|insert|drop|update|md5|benchmark|or|and|if) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (base64_encode|localhost|mosconfig) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (boot\.ini|echo.*kae|etc/passwd) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (GLOBALS|REQUEST)(=|\[|%) [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>

# 5G:[USER AGENTS]
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    # SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent ^$ keep_out
    SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent (binlar|casper|cmsworldmap|comodo|diavol|dotbot|feedfinder|flicky|ia_archiver|jakarta|kmccrew|nutch|planetwork|purebot|pycurl|skygrid|sucker|turnit|vikspider|zmeu) keep_out
    <limit GET POST PUT>
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
        Deny from env=keep_out
    </limit>
</IfModule>

# 5G:[REQUEST STRINGS]
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    RedirectMatch 403 (https?|ftp|php)\://
    RedirectMatch 403 /(https?|ima|ucp)/
    RedirectMatch 403 /(Permanent|Better)$
    RedirectMatch 403 (\=\\\'|\=\\%27|/\\\'/?|\)\.css\()$
    RedirectMatch 403 (\,|\)\+|/\,/|\{0\}|\(/\(|\.\.\.|\+\+\+|\||\\\"\\\")
    RedirectMatch 403 \.(cgi|asp|aspx|cfg|dll|exe|jsp|mdb|sql|ini|rar)$
    RedirectMatch 403 /(contac|fpw|install|pingserver|register)\.php$
    RedirectMatch 403 (base64|crossdomain|localhost|wwwroot|e107\_)
    RedirectMatch 403 (eval\(|\_vti\_|\(null\)|echo.*kae|config\.xml)
    RedirectMatch 403 \.well\-known/host\-meta
    RedirectMatch 403 /function\.array\-rand
    RedirectMatch 403 \)\;\$\(this\)\.html\(
    RedirectMatch 403 proc/self/environ
    RedirectMatch 403 msnbot\.htm\)\.\_
    RedirectMatch 403 /ref\.outcontrol
    RedirectMatch 403 com\_cropimage
    RedirectMatch 403 indonesia\.htm
    RedirectMatch 403 \{\$itemURL\}
    RedirectMatch 403 function\(\)
    RedirectMatch 403 labels\.rdf
    RedirectMatch 403 /playing.php
    RedirectMatch 403 muieblackcat
</IfModule>

# 5G:[REQUEST METHOD]
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
    RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>

# 5G:[BAD IPS]
<limit GET POST PUT>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    # uncomment/edit/repeat next line to block IPs
    # Deny from 123.456.789
</limit>



# compress text, HTML, JavaScript, CSS, and XML
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

# remove browser bugs
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent
```

how you can see i put your suggest on the top (now it's commented) but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `RedirectMatch` rule in the root .htaccess of `.net` site:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^_]+)_([^_/]+)/?$ http://www.dmbitalia.com/$1-$2.html
```

Comment: it doesn't work: every page of www.dmbitalia.net redirect to www.dmbitalia.com.
I need to redirect only the url`http://www.dmbitalia.net/articolo_somethingelse` to the page `http://www.dmbitalia.com/somethingelse-articolo.html`

Comment: Not sure how you're testing but it does redirect `/articolo_somethingelse` to `http://www.dmbitalia.com/somethingelse-articolo.html` on my Apache. Make sure you keep this rule right at top of your .htaccess and test after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: With this redirect rule at top what exact URL isn't working and what error do you get?